# Modal que abre só a primeira vez

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Sou novo aqui, tenho um modal que abre automaticamente, queria fazer ele abrir só a primeira vez pro usuário.
Vi que tem uma forma de fazer com cookies.
Só que sou bem leigo com jquery e não consegui fazer, alguem pode me ajudar?

```
insira o código aqui <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
/* The Modal (background) */.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
position: relative;
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 80%;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
-webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
animation-name: animatetop;
animation-duration: 0.4s
}
/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
to {top:0; opacity:1}
}
@keyframes animatetop {
from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
to {top:0; opacity:1}
}
/* The Close Button */
.close {
color: white;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
.modal-header {
padding: 2px 16px;
background-color: #5cb85c;
color: white;
}
.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}
.modal-footer {
padding: 2px 16px;
background-color: #5cb85c;
color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<h2>Modal Header</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Some text in the Modal Body</p><p>Some other text...</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$('.close').click(function(event){
$('#myModal').fadeOut();
event.preventDefault();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#myModal').modal('show');
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar o `localStorage`, que funciona como um *cookie*. Use o callback nativo do Bootstrap para criá-lo:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
   localStorage.setItem("modal", true);
});
```

Quando a modal abrir irá criar um `LS` (localStorage) chamado `modal` com um valor qualquer (coloquei `true` porque o valor não importa nesse caso).

Ao carregar a página você verifica se esse LS existe, caso não exista, o modal irá abrir normalmente:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var ls = localStorage.getItem("modal");
   if(!ls){
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
   }
})
```

Código JS completo:

```
$('.close').click(function(event){
   $('#myModal').fadeOut();
   event.preventDefault();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   var ls = localStorage.getItem("modal");
   if(!ls){
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
   }
})

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
   localStorage.setItem("modal", false);
});
```

> Não coloco um exemplo funcional aqui porque o snippet não aceita LS.

Comment: dvd, muito obrigado!!!
Funcionou perfeitamente!!!